# SQL MERGE to remote (linked) server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-merge

Is it possible to utilize the SQL MERGE function on a linked server's database table? The end goal is to synchronize the remote table with our local SQL server table. I’ve done some research online and couldn’t find any related information. If it is possible how would you setup the source and target statements?

Comment: Do you mean that the table is on a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)? Where is the *target* table located? From [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx): *"target_table cannot be a remote table."*

Comment: Yes, linked. It is located on in FL, i'm in CT.

Comment: Then you can not use `merge` if you want to merge from `CT` to `FL`.

Comment: thats a pitty... such a nice, easy feature...

Comment: You could reverse the job by using a stored procedure on the remote server merging from  where you are. You have to setup the reverse link of course.

Comment: where can i find any docs on that?

Comment: calling the MERGE from the remote server would be preferred anyway, even if you could call it from the local server, since performance on INSERT is so much better locally than remotely.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To reiterate the comment by @Mikael Eriksson, yes, you can.  The *target* of a MERGE cannot be remote, but the *source* of a MERGE can be remote.  So, if you can run the MERGE statement from your server in FL, then it is quite possible.  For example, you could run something like this on your remove server in FL:

```
MERGE INTO "local FL table" USING "CT server"."database"."schema"."same table" ON ...
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, i thought i hit a dead end when i got the error about the merge not being able to run with remote targets, but then i got the hint from your answer that i can swap servers and execute the query on the main server itself, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently my research wasn't good enough, it’s stated right on MSDN:
“target_table cannot be a remote table” ... so that answers this question...

Comment: If I am not going to use it for a remote table, its half worthless! It's like travelling 1000 miles route and having to leave your car and start walking after the 500th mile..

Comment: If you look up the docu for merge(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the target can not be a remote table. The source can however be a remote table. So, you can 'pull' data from a source, but you cannot 'push' data to a target.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact Answer of this Question. But an Alternate for Updating remote Table in the Linked Server.

```
UPDATE [RemoteItem] 
SET    [RemoteItem].[AccountID] = [I].[AccountID] 
FROM   OPENQUERY
(
    [LINKEDSERVER],
    'select AccountID from [RemoteDb].dbo.[Item]'
) [RemoteItem] 
INNER JOIN [LocalDB].[dbo].[Item] AS [I] 
    ON p.ProductID = oq.ProductID
```

Refere this [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/436634c6-07de-44ce-b27c-cafa62d781cb/how-to-update-remote-table-using-openquery)

Not Tested.

Comment: I have to give you props, because I never would have thought that this would work, but it's the only thing that solved my problem of trying to update a Remote Table from a local temp table select.

Answer (score -1):

Yoy can always use EXEC('SQL CODE HERE')AT YOUR_LINKED_SERVER in your server, maybe as a Stored Procedure.

This will execute the query you want on your linked server so you could merge a local table (target_table) with a server table (source).

This is a code I use in a Stored Procedure in my Server that its called from the client. Client exec stored procedure in server->Server Exec Query to update different linked servers (clients) with the same informacion (employees)

```
    EXEC('
SET IDENTITY_INSERT PVBC.DBO.empleadas ON

MERGE INTO PVBC.DBO.empleadas A
USING(
    SELECT id_empleada, nombre, apellidos
    FROM SERVIDOR.PVBC_SERVIDOR.DBO.empleadas) TA
ON (A.id_empleada =TA.id_empleada)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
    SET A.nombre=TA.nombre,
        A.apellidos=TA.apellidos
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    INSERT 
        (id_empleada, nombre, apellidos)
    VALUES
        (id_empleada, nombre, apellidos);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT PVBC.DBO.empleadas OFF
')AT MEGA --This is one of my linked servers
```

Comment: but this requires that the target server must have the source server as a linked server, which isn't always possible or desirable. In a way, this just flips the problem around.

Comment: @EdgarHolguin         Just to remind you, if the RPC calls aren't enable for remote servers the above won't work

Comment: Works perfectly, not sure why you're getting downvoted. This is an ideal solution. Obviously the server have to be linked and RPC has to be set up, but if you're not able to get those basic prerequisites set up, then you probably shouldn't be trying to merge cross-server in the first place.